# undefined index php array returning content

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$SampleArray`:

```
Array ( 
      [0] => Array ( 
             [0] => Array ( 
                    [ID] => 322 
                    [Number] => 1
                    [Date] => 3117-01-41 
                    [example] => Hello  )
             [1] => Array ( 
                    [ID] => 123 
                    [Number] => 49 
                    [Date] => 1717-05-21 
                    [example] => Hi )
             [2] => Array ( 
                    [ID] => 007A
                    [Number] => 42 
                    [Date] => 2005-11-24 
                    [example] => Some Text )
             )
      )
```

This is all in a function which only returns a content variable, it does not echo or print. Only the content variable is being appended and returned.

```
for($index=0; $index < count($sampleArray); $index++){
        $content .= '<p>'.$sampleArray[0]["Number"].'</p>';

    }
```

Returning this give me an  error

```
Undefined index:Number
```

Comment: You can't read the array or the for loop?

Comment: I would agree that `$sampleArray[0]["Number"]` doesn't exist as far as anyone can tell.

Comment: Even if i take out the [0] i get the same error. Any solutions @deceze

Comment: @jumpman8947 that's because you need an additional [0]

Comment: Now that I've formatted your output so you  can understand it, you should be able to see fairly obviously that you need **two** numeric identifiers, so : `$sampleArray[0][0]["Number"] === 1`